# jQuery versions overlapping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm working on a widget, that needs jQuery complete version and jQuery UI to work.(This widget should be able to be embedded in any website)

It works fine and like expected when i embed it in my project. But sometimes when i embed it in other project that has another JQuery library it brakes the code of my widget.

For instance, if the website has another jQuery version, i can check `if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined')` and don't use another version and ti works fine only if the defined version is a complete one, otherwise it won't work because it needs the complete version of jQuery.
Or if i use `jQuery.noConflict(true)`, it removed any other defined version and the widget works fine but sometimes it breaks the website (where the widget is embedded) because in this case jQuery is loaded at the end and any scripts that depends on it won't work.

I'm struggling with this issues for many days cause the widget needs to work fine where ever it's embedded and must not affect the **host website**. Any help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using somekind of pattern to protect the global scope (like IIFEs, modules or something) or are you putting it all in the global namespace ? If your code is using the global scope to run this is probably the problem.

Comment: I'm already defining all my widget code inside `(function(){})();`

Comment: Anyone could help me :(

Comment: Probably no one will. Your question is too generic, not testable. How can anyone help without a test environment where things can be investigated? Besides, even if you give all aspects someone needs to test your case, the amount of work to test would be prohibitive, as many different sites would have to be created to test several different conditions. An advice: create other, more focused question with all the code needed to reproduce the error in one site it occurs. Then maybe people can help you better.

Comment: Thx a lot @Nelson, sorry because i'm noobie in this foum. From now on i will be more careful about asking questions. I found out a tricky solution for my case. i defined a timeout for my widget 4000ms. after all the web page is loaded, the wedget lanches. i'm not sure if it's a best way to do but at least it works for now.

Comment: No problem. That's why I trying to show you how it works around here. About the timer... Onload event wouldn't be better ? Or at least do a setInterval checking if a certain element that interests you is already loaded?

Comment: okey i will try this solutions and stick with the suitable one for my case. Thx in advance.